# What is ST in PostGIS?

Tags: gis, postgis, spatial, terminology

Almost all the functions in PostGIS start with ST. e.g. ST_Distance_Sphere, ST_GeomFromText, ST_Intersection, etc.

What does ST mean?

http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a GIS term not a programming term. This question should be on [gis.se] (where it would be a duplicate)

Comment: @EvanCarroll -- Do you mean a duplicate of this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286808/what-does-the-st-prefix-stand-for-e-g-in-st-polygonize which was asked 7 years later?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html):

> PostGIS has begun a transition from the existing naming convention to
> an SQL-MM-centric convention. As a result, most of the functions that
> you know and love have been renamed using the standard **spatial type
> (ST)** prefix. Previous functions are still available, though are not
> listed in this document where updated functions are equivalent. These
> will be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: However, it originally meant *spatial-temporal* -- see http://doesen0.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/proceedings/paper/68.pdf

Comment: Cool - wasn't aware of that. Thanks for sharing - maybe that deserves to be an answer too?

Comment: The "Spatial and Temporal" @MartinF mentioned is in the last paragraph of Page 3.

Comment: Know and **love**...that's a **bold** assumption by the manual.

Answer (score 21):

Originally, it was for *spatial* and *temporal* data. From [http://doesen0.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/proceedings/paper/68.pdf](//http://doesen0.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/proceedings/paper/68.pdf):

> The SQL/MM standard uses consistently the prefix ST for all tables, views, types, methods,
>   and function names. The prefix stood originally for Spatial and Temporal. It was intended
>   in the early stages of the standard development to define a combination of temporal
>   and spatial extension. A reason for that was that spatial information is very often tied with
>   temporal data... During the development of SQL/MM
>   Spatial, it was decided that temporal has a broader scope beyond the spatial application... The contributors to SQL/MM did not want to move forward with a Spatio-temporal support until
>   SQL/Temporal developed.
>   ... Today, one might want to interpret it as Spatial Type.